# I give three arguments, the input df, the column I want to clean,the new column I want to be added with cleansed names. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

```
library(dplyr)
clean_name <- function(df,col_name,new_col_name){

 #remove whitespace and common titles.
 df$new_col_name <- mutate_all(df, 
                  trimws(gsub("MR.?|MRS.?|MS.?|MISS.?|MASTER.?","",df$col_name)))

 #remove any chunks of text where a number is present
 df$new_col_name<- transmute_all(df,
                  gsub("[^\\s]*[\\d]+[^\\s]*","",df$col_name,perl = TRUE))

}
```

I get the following error

> "Error: Column `new_col_name` must be a 1d atomic #vector or a list"

Comment: If you are passing only single column `mutate_all` or `transmute_all` is not needed.  It would be `mutate/transmute` and within that, you don't need `df$`.  are you passing the arguments unquoted.  In that case, use `enquo(colname)`, enquo(new_colname)` and then evaluate with `!!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want to do is make sure that the output of the functions you're using is either a vector or a list with only one dimension so that you can add it as a new column in the desired data frame. You can verify the class of an object with the Class function which comes within the base package.

The mutate function by itself should do what you want, it returns the same data frame but with the new column:

```
     library(dplyr)
     clean_name <- function(df, col_name, new_col_name) {

     # first_cleaning_to_colname = The first change you want to make to the col_name column. This should be a vector.
     # second_cleaning_to_colname = The change you're going to make to the col_name column after the first one. This should be a vector too.

     first_change <- mutate(df, col_name = first_cleaning_to_colname)

     second_change <- mutate(first_change, new_col_name = second_cleaning_to_colname)

     return(second_change)
     }
```

You can make both this changes at the same time but I thought this way it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If we are passing unquoted column names, then use

```
library(tidyverse)
clean_name <- function(df,col_name, new_col_name){
   col_name <- enquo(col_name)
  new_col_name <- enquo(new_col_name)
   df %>% 
     mutate(!! new_col_name := 
     trimws(str_replace_all(!!col_name, "MR.?|MRS.?|MS.?|MISS.?|MASTER.?","")) ) %>%
     transmute(!! new_col_name := trimws(str_replace_all(!! new_col_name, 
              "[^\\s]*[\\d]+[^\\s]*","")))
     }


clean_name(dat1, col1, colN) 
#   colN
#1  one
#2  two
```

#### data

```
dat1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("MR. one", "MS. two 24"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```